# I am trying to save data in Sugar DB(V 1.5)

Tags: android, database, sugarcrm

Is there any `.saveAll()` method which I can use to save all the instances of a list from an API at once instead of saving by `.save()` method by iterating through the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the example below. Hope this will help.

```
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
books.add(new Book("isbn123", "Title here", "2nd edition"))
books.add(new Book("isbn456", "Title here 2", "3nd edition"))
books.add(new Book("isbn789", "Title here 3", "4nd edition"))
SugarRecord.saveInTx(books);
```